# How to use a learnable parameter in pytorch, constrained between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I want to use a learnable parameter that only takes values between 0 and 1. How can I do this in pytorch?

Currently I am using:

```
self.beta = Parameter(torch.Tensor(1))
#initialize
zeros(self.beta)
```

But I am getting zeros and NaN for this parameter, as I train.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a "raw" parameter taking any values, and then pass it through a sigmoid function to get a values in range (0, 1) to be used by your function.

For example:

```py
class MyZeroOneLayer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    self.raw_beta = nn.Parameter(data=torch.Tensor(1), requires_grad=True)

  def forward(self):  # no inputs
    beta = torch.sigmoid(self.raw_beta)  # get (0,1) value
    return beta
```

Now you have a module with trainable parameter that is effectively in range (0,1)

Comment: Which mean to have a value of 1 you will need the parameter to be infinity. Not sure if that will work as intended.

Comment: This is incorrect. After sigmoid, self.raw_beta will no longer be a nn.Parameter.

Comment: @JackShi `self.raw_beta` will **always** be a `nn.Parameter`. The local variable `beta` inside `forward` method is not a parameter.