# Trainable parameter using PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

How can I integrate a trainable parameter ranging from 2 to 10 using PyTorch? This parameter doesn’t directly participate in the output operations, but its updates need to be maintained during training.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by two different ways:

1. clamp method (hard limiting):

```
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(100.0), requires_grad=True)

# use this in your train loop after optimizer.step() in order to clip it in-place and keep it in your desired range every time it is updated
a.data.clamp_(min=2, max=10)
```

2. sigmoid method (soft limiting):

```
a = torch.tensor(100.0)
a = torch.nn.Parameter(2 + torch.sigmoid(a) * (10 - 2),  requires_grad=True)
# param `a` will be a parameter limited between 2 and 10
```

References:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/set-constraints-on-parameters-or-layers/23620/7
[How to use a learnable parameter in pytorch, constrained between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022269/how-to-use-a-learnable-parameter-in-pytorch-constrained-between-0-and-1)
[How can I limit the range of parameters in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66258464/how-can-i-limit-the-range-of-parameters-in-pytorch)
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.clamp_.html